# Google Maps Android API v2 animate GoogleMap View

Tags: android

I am trying to animate that wraps the Google Maps Fragment in my layout.  The following animation appears to have no effect.

```
ObjectAnimator mapAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", -view.getHeight(), view.getHeight());
```

I have tried wrapping the  fragment in FrameLayout and animating that with no luck.  I can only seem to hide and show the map with the FragmentManager.

According to this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=animation&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=4782&) the Google Map uses a SurfaceView which can't be animated.  I cannot find anything official to support this.  Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot find anything official to support this.

If "this" means the fact that Maps V2 uses `SurfaceView`, [drop a `ViewServer` in your app](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer), hook up Hierarchy View to your app running on a Maps V2-capable device, and see what you see. Cyril Mottier wrote comment #1 on the issue you cited; since he says it is a `SurfaceView`, I believe him.

If "this" means the fact that `SurfaceView` cannot be animated, that is confirmed by reading [the documentation for `TextureView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html).

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea about the Hierarchy View tool.  It sounds like an extremely useful tool for dumb questions like mine :P.  I didn't realize that was Cyril either!

Comment: @jophde: It's not a dumb question -- not knowing things like this is one of the problems with closed-source libraries.